# Setting up permissions on Windows network share

Tags: windows, permissions

I have a specific folder setup on my corporate network that I need to manage the permissions for and the process isn't going to scale gracefully.

I have a folder named `Projects` and within that one a folder for each project, say A, B, C. The tree structure looks like this:

```
Projects - Project A
         - Project B
         - Project C
```

A few people are assigned to each project so it could look like this:

```
Project A - Members 1, 2, 3
Project B - Members 1, 4, 5
Project C - Members 1, 2, 6
```

When I create the folder for project C I give permissions to members 2 and 6 to that folder. When member 6 tries to navigate to it it won't work until I give him permission to the folder `Projects` as well.

Question: When I add user 6 to the folder `Projects` he is also added to projects A and B (inheritance) and I have to go into each one of them and deny the user. Once I have a few projects going I need to go into each one of the projects and remove them one by one, something that might lead to mistakes.

Is there a better way of setting up the permissions?

Answer (score 1):

I would create a security group for each Project folder and assign users to that group.  Then assign that security group to the Project A, B, C folders.

We have used this as people are added to a Project team, they are added to the security group for the  project folder for that specific project.  If they leave the project, they are simply removed from that security group.

So if we have a new project called Acme, we create a folder and a security group called Acme.  Users are added to the Security Group and that group is assigned to the Acme folder with appropriate permissions

Answer (score 0):

At the parent folder, Projects, grant read permission to Everyone with the Apply To option set to "This folder only".  Then give individual permissions to just the specific folder(s).